# 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll when exporting huge Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-3, epplus

I am trying to export an Excel file with 1,800,000+ rows of data with 9 columns using EPPlus. I used a DataSet and separate it into batch (100,000 each DataTable). Currently, it can export at max of 1,000,000 rows.

Here's my code for export below:

```
    public FileContentResult ExportInventory()
    {
         DataSet dsInventory = Session["Live_Inventory"] as DataSet;

         var filename = "Excel Inventory.xlsx";
         var excelContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
         byte[] excelContent = ExportExcel(dsInventory);

         return File(excelContent, excelContentType, filename);
    }

    public byte[] ExportExcel(DataSet dsInventory)
    {
         byte[] result = null;
         ExcelWorksheet workSheet = null;

         var package = new ExcelPackage();
         for (int tbl = 1; tbl <= dsInventory.Table.Count; tbl++)
         {
              workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(String.Format("Sheet " + tbl));
              workSheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dsInventory.Tables[tbl], true);                  
         }

         result = package.GetAsByteArray();//Exception occurs here when table count > 10 
         return result;
    }
```

Comment: Why dont  you just write this directly to the file? `.xlsx` is just a pack of `.xml` files ..

Comment: How? by creating first an temp excel file, save it, then open to write there?

Comment: Create a zip file and then inside of this zip file you can just throw your data in. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082278/how-to-properly-assemble-a-valid-xlsx-file-from-its-internal-sub-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082278/how-to-properly-assemble-a-valid-xlsx-file-from-its-internal-sub-components)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void DataToExcel(DataTable dataToConvert, HttpResponse response)
{
    FileInfo myFile = new FileInfo("~/MyProject/Inventory.xlsx");
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(myFile))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

        worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataToConvert, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light1);

        package.Save();


        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", "Inventory.xlsx"));
        response.WriteFile("~/MyProject/Inventory.xlsx");
        response.Flush();
        response.End();

    }

}
```

Comment: @JosephLYapcengcoJr  So what is your final goal? You want to convert your data to excel and save it to the server or download it on client side? or anything else?

Comment: convert it to excel then download it on client.

Comment: I don't think your code will solve my problem because you just added methods in downloading a file and my problem is when I'm converting "package = new ExcelPackage();"  to byte array when the datatable's rows reach 1M+, the System.OutOfMemoryException occurs. Anyway, thanks for your help!..

Comment: @JosephLYapcengcoJr  Try the following: create excel file in your project manually, say inventory.xlsx . Then write data in that file using LoadFromDataTable method and finally download the file via HttpResponse. This way you will bypass the convertion of package to the byte array which overloads your memory. I have edited my code above. Hope that helps

Comment: I tried to use your code but it still returns 'System.OutOfMemoryException' on `package.Save();` So I replaced the part that using EPPlus library with an OpenXML here's the [code](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/659666/Export-very-large-data-to-Excel-file) -the ExportToOXML method only and it works!, Thanks for helping! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer:**

You should have a look at this: [Export large data to an exel file](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/659666/Export-very-large-data-to-Excel-file)

This should definitely help you out.

Comment: yes I can get my resources but the package will be closed once it executes the package.GetAsByteArray();

Comment: I tried to use your code but it still returns 'System.OutOfMemoryException' on that same line. I wasn't able to try adding `await Task.Delay(5000);` because it is only available in Framework 4.5 (my project is using .net Framework is 4). Thanks for helping! :)