# XLSX corrupt after accidental open & save in Notepad

Tags: excel, xlsx, space, data-recovery, nul

Is there a programmatic, built-in, or external method to recover a corrupt Excel file?

I accidentally opened my `.XLSX` file (`Excel 2010`) in `Windows Notepad`, added a line of recognizable text, and saved it. Now the file cannot be opened by Excel, as the internally compressed `.XLSX` file cannot be uncompressed.

### My research showed me that:

1. The `.XLSX` file is a [compressed archive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11116875/8112776), starting with `PK…`.
2. By saving the file in Notepad, all [`Null`/`\0` characters](http://www.bluesock.org/~willg/dev/ascii.html) were replaced with spaces (`0x20`).
3. Before the mistake happened, the file contained already several hundreds of `0x20` characters, so *replacing* all `0x20` with `0x00` won't help.

Any ideas are appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is off-topic as it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Which version of Excel?  What happens when you try to open it?

Comment: A long shot, I doubt it would work, but have you tried the Open and Repair option within excel?

Comment: What sort of ideas are you after? Other than "restore from backup"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, that sucks, *bigtime*.

I've seen lots of corrupt files caused lots of different ways but that's a new one.

That series of events if probably near the top of the list of "Things not to do to Excel files."  *We're sorry, we'll have to suspend your "Excel Operator's License".*

I guess there's a couple things you could try...,

---

## Plan A

Is there any chance you have **Autorecover** turned on?  If not, you should probably turn them on now, for *"next time"*.

If it is on, then hopefully the ***Document Recovery task pane*** appears when you try to open the file (in Excel).  If so, see:

> - Office.com : **[Recover your Office Files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/recover-your-office-files-dc901de2-acae-47f2-9175-fb5a91e9b3c8)**

Even if your file doesn't show up in that dialog, double-check all of the folders/files located in the default AutoRecover save location to see if a recent version was saved, "just in case":

> ### `%AppData%\Microsoft\Excel`

---

## Plan B:

**Since an `XLSX` file is actually just a `.ZIP` file**, there's a chance you may be able to use *WinZip* or a *ZIP Repair Utility* to recover your data (depending, of course, on how badly you messed it up.)

- Change the file's extension to `.ZIP` and open it with WinZip.
- It may try to repair the file, and if it does it might even succeed (on some or all "parts").
- Put all the files back into a new `.ZIP`.
- Change the extension back to `.XLS`.
- Cross you fingers and try opening it with Excel.

There are also lots of standalone [`ZIP` Repair Utilities](https://www.google.ca/search?q=zip%20file%20repair&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=1D-EWsbHONfcjwPY34DwDA) out there, so  ***you could try a few others*** with the same process.

I have no idea if any will actually work in this case, but please **report back if you do end up trying any of them** (whether or not they fix it), so we all know.

### More about Excel File Structure:

- [XML & ZIP: Explore Your Excel Workbooks File Structure](http://professor-excel.com/xml-zip-excel-file-structure/)

---

## Plan C:

Short of that working, you could try opening it back up in Notepad and see if there's any legible data you can copy & paste out manually...  might be there a while, if there's anything at all...

---

## Plan D:

<sup>There is no Plan C. *Sorry, you're SOL.*</sup>

### How to turn on AutoRecover *(for next time)*:

1. Click `File` → `Options` → `Save`
2. Make sure the Save AutoRecover information every *x* minutes box is selected

> **Important:** Even after turning AutoRecover on, the [image] Save button is still your best friend.
>
> To be sure you don’t lose your latest work, click Save Button [image]
>   (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) often.

[image: dialog screenshot]

Oh, and in the future:

> Don't open *Excel* files in anything but *Excel*.

---

### Source & More Info:

- Office.com: [Use *AutoSave* and *AutoRecover* to help protect your files in case of a crash](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-autosave-and-autorecover-to-help-protect-your-files-in-case-of-a-crash-551c29b1-6a4b-4415-a3ff-a80415b92f99)

---

[image: Sudoku]

Comment: _"Don't open Excel files in anything but Excel."_ Where's that quote from? Please provide attribution for quotes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit -- Hmm, I can't remember where I heard that...  Wasn't it a Bill Gates quote?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the huge load of tips!

Comment: You're welcome.  Any chance you got it working?  